# Boggle type word checker using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am trying to create a variation of a Boggle type word checker using jQuery. The variation is that a letter can be used more than once and the board is always two lines.

I have been using a string divided in half as the 'board', and using a recursive function to search for a given word. I have looked at similar examples but cannot seem to code the function correctly.

For example, if the board string is `OMRAWNLET`. The board would look like:

```
O M R A W  
N L E T
```

It would return `true` if the word to search for is `watermelon`.  Can anyone please guide me or write the function? Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first by doing some research on the subject and making an attempt to write the code. If you have issues with that code, then feel free to ask a question requesting debugging help. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So sorry for not posting my attempted code. I guess I was just embarrassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a two dimentional array for the board and an array of letters for the word.
Here's a quick prototype:

```js
var isWordOnTheBoard = function(board, word) {
    var passedTest = true;
    var previousLetterCoordinates;
    
    //written as a loop; rewrite to use recursion
    for (let letter of word) {
        // console.log('current letter is ' + letter);
        var letterCoordinates = getCoordinatesOnTheBoard(board, letter);
        if(!letterCoordinates){
            passedTest = false;
            console.log('letter ' + letter + ' is not on the board');
            break;
        }
        if(previousLetterCoordinates && !areNeighbors(previousLetterCoordinates, letterCoordinates)){
            passedTest = false;
            console.log('letter ' + letter + ' is not a neighbor to the previous letter');
            break;
        }
        previousLetterCoordinates = letterCoordinates;
    }
    return passedTest;
};

//assumes letters on the board are unique with no repeated letters
var getCoordinatesOnTheBoard = function(board, letter) {
    //undefined means letter is not on the board
    var coordinates;
    
    var firstRowIndex = board[0].indexOf(letter);
    if(firstRowIndex >= 0){
        coordinates = {
            row: 0,
            column: firstRowIndex
        };
    }
    
    var secondRowIndex = board[1].indexOf(letter);
    if(secondRowIndex >= 0){
        coordinates = {
            row: 1,
            column: secondRowIndex
        };
    }
    
    
    return coordinates;
}
//neighbors of a:
// | NW | N | NE |
// | W  | a | E  |
// | SW | S | SE |
// where NW is North West, N is North, NE is North East and so on

var areNeighbors = function(a, b) {
    var nw_of_a = {
        row: a.row - 1,
        column: a.column - 1
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(nw_of_a)){return true}
    var n_of_a = {
        row: a.row - 1,
        column: a.column
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(n_of_a)){return true}
    
    var ne_of_a = {
        row: a.row - 1,
        column: a.column + 1
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(ne_of_a)){return true}
    
    var e_of_a = {
        row: a.row,
        column: a.column + 1
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(e_of_a)){return true}
    
    var se_of_a = {
        row: a.row + 1,
        column: a.column + 1
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(se_of_a)){return true}
    
    var s_of_a = {
        row: a.row + 1,
        column: a.column
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(s_of_a)){return true}
    
    var sw_of_a = {
        row: a.row + 1,
        column: a.column - 1
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(sw_of_a)){return true}
    
    var w_of_a = {
        row: a.row,
        column: a.column - 1
    }
    if (JSON.stringify(b) === JSON.stringify(w_of_a)){return true}
    
    return false;
}

var omraw_nlet = [
    ['O','M','R','A','W'],
    ['N','L','E','T']
];
var watermelon = ['W', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'R', 'M', 'E', 'L', 'O', 'N'];
var lemon = ['L', 'E', 'M', 'O', 'N'];

console.log(isWordOnTheBoard(omraw_nlet, watermelon)); //true
console.log(isWordOnTheBoard(omraw_nlet, ['W', 'A', 'R'])); //true
console.log(isWordOnTheBoard(omraw_nlet, lemon)); //true
console.log(isWordOnTheBoard(omraw_nlet, lemon.concat(['S']))); //false
console.log(isWordOnTheBoard(omraw_nlet, ['T', 'E', 'N'])); //false
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to code this. It will help me further understand Java.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are wanting to check is if the inputted word is valid based on the letters on the board, you can do that rather simply. Just pass the letters as an array and input as a string. From there simply search letter by letter through input to see if it's in the letters array.

```js
function validate_input(letters, input){
input = input.toUpperCase();

  var errors = input.split("").filter(function(letter){
    return (letters.indexOf(letter) == -1);
  });

 return (errors == "");
}

var letters = ["O","M","R","A","W","N","L","E","T"];

console.log(validate_input(letters, "lemfon"));
console.log(validate_input(letters, "watermelon"));
```